# How to get one by one values(value in array) from Key Json?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I am getting values together from one key. Because in my case multiple values in array form come into the one key.

**JSON**

```
  engine_data: {
    internal: {
       poling: {
          account: [
             "2009-38554",
             "2009-38554"
             ],
          secure: [
             "2008-11833"
            ]
         }
      }
    }
```

**Javascript:**

```
call.all('xyz').get(id).then(function(resp)
      {
        var res=resp.data;
        var jsonData = 
        res.engine_data.internal.poling;
        for(var i in jsonData){       
          if(i == "account")
          {          
            alert(jsonData[i]);
            alert(jsonData[i].length);           
            var account = jsonData[i].join(",")
            $scope.acount = www.xyz/+account;
          }if (i == "secure") {            
            var secure = jsonData[i].join(",")
            $scope.secure = www.abc/+secure;
          }         

        }
```

In my Json value in array form, So account (keys) has two value in array form. When I put in alert for printing then both value print together.

**Screen Shot:**
[image]

So I want to append these two value in www.xyz/ url.

**Like out put result should be**
www.xyz/2009-38554 
www.xyz/2009-38554

But Right now I am getting

www.xyz/2009-38554,2009-38554

Share your ideas thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate over the array you get from `account` key and make all possible urls you can form values in array and you can make `$scope.account` an array and push all possible combinations, something like this:

```
for(var i in jsonData){       
  if(i == "account")
  {          
    alert(jsonData[i]);
    alert(jsonData[i].length);           

    $scope.account = [];
    var account = jsonData[i];
    for(var i=0; i<account.length; i++)
       $scope.acount.push("www.xyz/"+account[i]);
  }if (i == "secure") {            
    var secure = jsonData[i].join(",")
    $scope.secure = www.abc/+secure;
  }         

}
```

Comment: Thanks save my time.Can we separate two simple URL, Because right now It is showing. ["xyz/009090",xyz/90909]

Comment: not sure i understand what you are asking for, they are already separate in the array.

Comment: Right now It is appended the but again you are implementing array. SO two url in array form. Like ["url1","url2"]

Comment: yes they are two separate urls in the array, loop over the array and use them where you need them.